# Parse XML and fill string with element value

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, web-services, properties

I'm testing data binding and calling web services in WPF.  I'm using a web service which returns the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
    <NewDataSet> 
         <Table> 
            <AtomicWeight>4.0026</AtomicWeight> 
         </Table> 
    </NewDataSet>
</string>
```

And I'm trying to take the Atomic Weight and assign that string to a property called LookupOutput.

I've followed XPath tutorials and LINQ tutorials but haven't been able to find one which is simplified enough for this example.  What is the cleanest way to get to single elements from XML in a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string xml = @"<string xmlns=""http://www.webserviceX.NET"">
    <NewDataSet> <Table> <AtomicWeight>196.967</AtomicWeight> </Table> </NewDataSet>
    </string>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr); //or XDocument.Load(filename)
XNamespace ns = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";
string atomicWeight = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "AtomicWeight").First().Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  This gives me an InvalidOperationException was unhandled error, my XDocument is parsing a string which contains the XML, I wonder if the problem lies there?  I have a 'sequence contains no elements' detail in the error.

Comment: Using XDocument.Load(xmlString); returns an error detailing the XML contains illegal characters.

Comment: @mrEmpty My guess you real xml is different than the one you posted since this answer works for your xml

Comment: This is the link to the webservice I'm using: [link](http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx/GetAtomicWeight) and how I'm currently grabbing and using it: `var xDoc = XDocument.Load(wsm.GetAtomicWeight(lookupInput));
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";
            LookupOutput = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "AtomicWeight").First().Value;`

Comment: I have this working, going from L.B's answer above I wrote the following: `var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(wsm.GetAtomicWeight(lookupInput));
            XNamespace ns = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";
            LookupOutput = xDoc.Descendants("AtomicWeight").First().Value;`